# Java ArrayList memory usage with recursion

Tags: java, memory, arraylist

I'm just reviewing some code and have come across an issue I'm not able to explain conclusively, most likely as my Java is a bit rusty... The code is taking a nested collection of nodes and flattening.

This is the original snippet:

```
private static List<NavigationNode> flatten(
        List<NavigationNode> nodes,
        List<NavigationNode> flattenedNodes) {
    if (nodes == null || nodes.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    for (NavigationNode node : nodes) {
        flattenedNodes.add(node);
        flattenedNodes.addAll(flatten(node.getChildren(), flattenedNodes));
    }
    return flattenedNodes;
}
```

The problem I'm seeing, is when the nested list grows large enough, a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is thrown.

If I new up the flattened list rather than passing as a parameter and refactor as:

```
private static List<NavigationNode> flatten(
        List<NavigationNode> nodes) {
    if (nodes == null || nodes.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    List<NavigationNode> flattenedNodes = new ArrayList<NavigationNode>();
    for (NavigationNode node : nodes) {
        flattenedNodes.add(node);
        flattenedNodes.addAll(flatten(node.getChildren()));
    }
    return flattenedNodes;
}
```

The memory error no longer occurs.

Any help, excellent descriptions or further refactorings would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `I vaguely understand this is because under the covers, each call to add() is making a copy of the array`, not as far as I can tell, unless you are using `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Comment: OK I may be mistaken then. Looking at the trace in memory dump I have, I can see `java.util.Arrays.copyOf` being called which is what lead me to the conclusion. But you're saying this is not the case?

Comment: No, the array is only resized occasionally.

Comment: Understood, have removed my incorrect understanding :) thanks

Comment: Well, if your NavigationNode has a dependency (loop), it is going to be a race between OutOfMemory and StackOverflow. Doesn't seem to be the case though (because the alternative code works). Also, as a side note: Your algorithm is basically DFS, you have a (directed) graph, and you do a DFS to discover it and get a list of all the vertices in the graph.

Comment: @KevinPaton What's the difference?

Comment: @KevinPaton If you type one `=`, a compilation error happens. I can't see anything tricky in tracking it down. The only time this would compile is if you're doing it with a `Boolean` type variable, but even then it would blow up straight away with an `NPE` when you tried to run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the first snippet will try to add the contents of `flattenedNodes` to itself.

Think about a simple example when `node1` has one child, called `node2`. What happens here?

```
for (NavigationNode node : nodes) {
    flattenedNodes.add(node);
    flattenedNodes.addAll(flatten(node.getChildren(), flattenedNodes));
}
```

1. First `node1` is added to `flattenedNodes`
2. Then `flatten()` is called on the second level.
3. `node2` is added to `flattenedNodes` too.
4. When `flatten()` is finished, it returns `flattenedNodes`.
5. ...which is immediately `addAll()`-ed to `flattenedNodes` and BANG!

For every node visited the size of the list roughly doubles, so no wonder things get out of hand quickly.

One way to fix it is indeed what you did, the other would be to replace `flattenedNodes.addAll(flatten(node.getChildren(), flattenedNodes));` with simply `flatten(node.getChildren(), flattenedNodes)`. (And you can also change the return type of `flatten()` to `void` now.) I have to say though, I prefer your solution, it's more readable even if maybe slightly more wasteful.

Comment: Ah I think I'm following now. So because it's being passed as a reference, it ends up trying to add flattenedNodes to itself which will grown exponentially?

Comment: @timothyclifford Yes, that's exactly what happens. Add a `System.out.println(flattenedNodes.size());` line before `return` to see it even better.